# Python - differ between sentence ending and other full stops

Tags: python, string

I am trying to clean a text, in this example an article. Because i get the text in one long line, i want to put every sentence into a new line, so i simply did this:

`content.replace(".", ".\n")`

Well, it didnt work. The article contained stuff like `e.g.` `Dr. Taylor` `Train Nr. 11512` so obviously, my result looked pretty stupid.

Does anyone have an idea what i can use to reliably filter out these "non-sentence ending" full stops from *actual* full stops? In this case, i could just check if the string in front of the full stop is an actual word, by checking if it contains a vowel and a consonant i guess. But in general, i have no idea what i can do here.

Comment: Show input and expected output text

Comment: A guesstimate is you can check the length of word (whether <3) before the full stop. Normally they tend to be short for non-sentence-ending cases.

Comment: How long is the text? How many false positives do you have? Is the number small enough that you can correct them manually? Or is it a requirement that the conversion has to be completely automated?

Comment: Make a list of `e.g.`, `Dr.`, `Nr.`, and skip those when inserting your newlines (explicitly or with a regex).

Comment: This quickly devolves into a pretty complex topic in the realm of *natural language processing*… There is no *easy* solution.

Comment: Voting close based on too broad and op's inability to clarify the question.

Comment: My question was if there was a solution to this, how am i supposed to know if there isnt a python module that tries to do exactly this? The text and the size dont matter, like i said i am looking for a general appliable solution. Yes, @brevno, that is what im doing, but like i said - i was wondering if there was a module that tries to automate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This approach:

```
import re

text = """\
Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.
"""
sentences = re.split(r'(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s', text)

for stuff in sentences:
        print(stuff)
```

Output:

```
Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it.
Did he mind?
Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't.
In any case, this isn't true...
Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't.
```

First block: `(?<!\w\.\w.)` : this pattern searches in a negative feedback loop `(?<!)` for all words `(\w)` followed by fullstop `(\.)` , followed by other words `(\.)`

Second block: `(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)`: this pattern searches in a negative feedback loop for anything starting with uppercase alphabets `([A-Z])`, followed by lower case alphabets `([a-z])` till a dot `(\.)` is found.

Third block: `(?<=\.|\?)`: this pattern searches in a feedback loop of dot `(\.)` OR question mark `(\?)`

Fourth block: `(\s|[A-Z].*)`: this pattern searches after the dot OR question mark from the third block. It searches for blank space `(\s)` OR any sequence of characters starting with a upper case alphabet `([A-Z].*)`. This block is important to split if the input is as

Comment: Oh damn, i dont get all of it, but it looks promising, i didnt do much with RegEx before so thanks a lot! Only thing this didnt catch in my article is "Mio." as a (german) abbreviation for million, but im sure i can figure something out for that!

Comment: @FlyingThunder It's a good start but you will still need to deal with the exceptions. It won't catch any 3 letter case (`"etc., PhD., Eng."`). Also, you want it to behave this way and  not to blindly catch all those cases or you might end up with something like: "Mr. Jones does more than what he is paid for. He is such a generous guy. \n"

Comment: Please explain what cases this does handle and how it handles them. Without explanation this is unreliable copy-paste black magic.

Answer (score 3):

I know, this doesn't really answers your question, but if you just want to 'clean' the text in order to print it nicely, you could insert the new line after a set number of characters rather then the end of a sentence:

```py
text = """Does anyone have an idea what i can use to reliably filter out these "non-sentence ending" full stops from actual full stops? In this case, i could just check if the string in front of the full stop is an actual word, by checking if it contains a vowel and a consonant i guess. But in general, i have no idea what i can do here."""

text = text.split(' ')
line_length = 0
index = 0

for word in text:
    if (line_length + len(word)) < 70:
        index += 1
        line_length += len(word) + 1
    else:
        text.insert(index, '\n')
        index += 2
        line_length = len(word) + 1

print(' '.join(text))
```

The output would be:

```
Does anyone have an idea what i can use to reliably filter out these 
 "non-sentence ending" full stops from actual full stops? 
 In this case, i could just check if the string in front of the full 
 stop is an actual word, by checking if it contains a vowel and a consonant 
 i guess. But in general, i have no idea what i can do here.
```

Comment: thats actually a pretty good idea and it doesnt even need regex, thanks!

Comment: Pretty clever solution to a non-asked question, well done! =)

Comment: @FlyingThunder So I just stumbled across the textwraper module, wich does exaclty what I atempted here, only better. It even has a feature to detect sentences, however, it faces the exact same problems you addressed in your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is not trivial and should account for many exceptions. Plus, without an example we can only give broad suggestions.
However, you can add few rules that can be quickly implemented to improve your [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I guess that allows for more flexibility than replace.

1. There is always a space after a period and the following sentence should start with a capital letter. Hence you should use a `regex` that takes that into account. `[A-Z]` is to match any uppercase letter between A and Z.
2. Make a list of your exceptions `"Dr., Nr., Mr. Eng., PhD., Ph.D., George W. Bush", etc.` and do not replace those cases (as suggested by  brevno in his comment). These might end up being too many cases but you can capture most of these exception by adding the following rules.

   2.1.  If the word preceding the period has no vowels you don't cut.

   2.2. If the word preceding the period has only one or two letters you don't cut.

You will probably need to consider many other exceptions but these are the ones that come off the top of my head.

Comment: Yea, it would probably be the least amount of work to just handmake a list of exceptions, but i was hoping for a module that does something like spellcheck the sentence preceeding the full stop, because if a module would exist that checks the language and then spellchecks to verify if it is an actual sentence, it could be applied to any text. Well, good enough i guess, ill just test a lot more